# Java Bytebuffer Filling up completely

Tags: java, arrays, nio, bytebuffer

I am currently using the Java ByteBuffer

```
    ByteBuffer batch = ByteBuffer.allocate(tuple_size * batch_size ) ;
    int pos = 0;
    int sent = 0;
    while ( sent++ < batch_size) {
            Event event = (Event) it.next();
            batch.put(event.getData(), pos, tuple_size);
            pos += tuple_size;

        }
    return batch.array();
```

Currently, batch_size is set to 2. My issue is that on the second round, I get an IndexOutofBoundsException which I cannot explain given that, printing out the follwoing details:

```
       System.out.println(pos + " " +  batch.capacity() +  " " + batch.position() + " " +  batch.remaining());
```

I get: 
0   200 0   200  (round 0)

100 200 100 100  (round 1)

which is what one would expect. Now, based on the documentation, it seems that the bound checks do hold:

```
 offset - The offset within the array of the first byte to be read; must be non-negative and no larger than array.length
 length - The number of bytes to be read from the given array; must be non-negative and no larger than array.length - offset
```

How do I completely fill up the buffer? (whilst keeping the underlying buffer to have length tuple_size * batch_size?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need the *pos* variable. The `put` method is trying to read into `event.getData()` at position *pos*, while I think you want to read `event.getData()` from position 0. You can simply use `batch.put(event.getData())` to append the whole content of the array into the buffer.

Comment: Reading the documentation, this makes perfect sense. That's not how I expected the relative put operation to work.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no relative `put()` function for arrays; if you need it something like that, you'll have to call `position()` first, then `put()`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. As Buhb said I wasn't expecting put to work that way.  But rather that the offset was relative to the ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not apparent from your question if tuple_size is big enough for event.getData().
If not, that would result in your IndexOutofBoundsException.
Perhaps it's off by one?

Another possibility is that your iterator `it` only contains one element.

Edit: According to the documentation, you should get a BufferOverflowException if your buffer runs out of space. 
Quote from the documentation:

> This method transfers bytes into this buffer from the given source
>   array. If there are more bytes to be copied from the array than remain
>   in this buffer, that is, if length > remaining(), then no bytes are
>   transferred and a BufferOverflowException is thrown.

This points at that your problem isn't what you expect.

Comment: event.getData() is always equal to tuple_size and the queue always contain 1024 elements by default as well

Comment: I get an IndexArrayOutofBound Exception. Not a BufferOverflowException because the checkBound method fails. But I don't know why it fails.